# WCF Windows Authentication silverlight login screen

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, web-services

I have a WCF service with the given security in my config:

```
<security mode="Transport">
   <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```

I am connecting to my WCF service with Silverlight over a `basicHttpBinding`. What I want, is when my silverlight application starts, they input their windows login/password (this is an intranet app).

In Silverlight, I am able to set my username and password before making any calls.  However, if I put an incorrect password or username, I get an error returned (http 500 I believe).

```
ServiceManager.exporterClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myUserName";
ServiceManager.exporterClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "myPassword";
```

Making a login screen in Silverlight is simple enough, but how can I call a function on my WCF service to ask if this given username and password is valid if it just returning and error because the windows credentials are invalid to begin with and therefore can not call the service?

Comment: If you use ASP.NET authentication and disable anonymous authentication, you don't need to worry about this.  The user will be prompted with their browser's login popup as soon as they visit the website.

Comment: So is there not a way to do it the way I described?

Comment: I was just trying to show you an easier way to do it.  The problem is you are requiring authentication on the service with the same credentials you want the service to check.  So if they credentials are invalid, you will be unable to check them.  You will have to make a separate WCF service that has no authentication and perform this check there.  However, as I stated, using ASP.NET authentication on the whole website is much easier.

Comment: This link might also be of use to you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx

Comment: @cadrell0 I tried using ASP.NET authentication, but it looks like it is wanting to authenticate through a SQL Server. I just want to verify the user's windows credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I have been implementing integrated authentication in a Silverlight PRISM based application and I found Various posts by Mike Taulty invaluable.

Here is a search result on his blog, he has 6 blog entries all well worth a read/watch

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/search.aspx?q=RIA+Services

Answer (score 0):

First Silverlight has nothing with Win Auth. It is managed by browser and since it uses Kerberos methodology your credentials are converted to a token. Setting your WCF service as WinAuth, Browser asks for Windows credentials and this user is checked at Active Directory both at client and server side automatically because your credentials are passed to server attached to your call as Kerberos tokens. There is an other issue here which is setting your site as trusted in your browser. This enables your WinAuth without prompt screen by using your computers current users credentials.

Regards,
Şerif